# Reseting URL in Django through views.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url, redirect

I am using Python 3.6, Django 1.11 with Salesforce NPSP as my back-end.

I have an issue, where I generate a User activation link URL & send mail to the user.

Once user clicks & confirms, he will be logged-in & allowed to use the application.

The url which I generate for mail activation is something like below, it has token values in it

```
localhost:8080/naka/activation/abg479843fiuegf/hfduige433274
```

Once user clicks above url he will be taken to home page which is

```
localhost:8080/naka/activation/abg479843fiuegf/hfduige433274/home.html
```

I am looking to reset the above url as

```
localhost:8080/naka/home.html
```

Reason being it will be easy to access my other pages like

```
localhost:8080/naka/aboutus.html
localhost:8080/naka/contactus.html
```

and so on

I have added my view.py file which has activation method in it

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):

context=locals()
try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    user = uid

except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError):
    user = None

if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
    login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
    return render(request,'home/home.html',context)
    #return HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost:8000/naka/home.html')
else:
    return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

I have also added a line from my urls.py file related to activation

```
url(r'^naka/activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    views.activate, name='activate'),
```

Comment: After logging in you should redirect.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Once the user clicks on the link, I want to login & redirect him to particular page with clean url. At the moment it does get redirected but with activation token in the url, which causes problem while accessing other  pages

Comment: No, currently there is no redirection here at all - you commented it out and replaced it with a `render` call.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes I am looking for more of good way to redirection
HttpResponseRedirect is kind of hard-coding, so I commented it

Answer (score 0):

change your activate method by:-

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):

try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
    user = None
if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
    user.is_active = True
    user.profile.email_confirmed = True
    user.save()
    login(request, user)
    return redirect('home')
else:
    return render(request, 'account_activation_invalid.html')
```

and your URL should be like:-

```
   url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',core_views.activate, name='activate'),
```

Do minor changes accordingly...